# Linear independence question 5

Tags: linear-algebra

($a_1,a_2,...a_n$) is a list of linearly independent vectors contained in the vector space $U$

$a_{n+1}$ is **not** an element of the span of the list ($a_1,a_2,...a_n$)

prove that the list ($a_1,a_2,...a_n,a_{n+1}$) is linearly independent

Comment: I don't know how to start

Comment: Can you write down, in mathematical terms, what it means for $a_{n+1}$ to be in the span of $\{a_1,,...,a_n\}$? From here, the statement will automatically follow.

Comment: Please do not deface your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeking a contradiction, suppose $\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n,a_{n+1}\}$ is linearly dependent, so the equation
$$
\lambda_1\cdot a_1+\dotsb+\lambda_n\cdot a_n+\lambda_{n+1}\cdot a_{n+1}=\mathbf 0\tag{1}
$$
has a solution where $\lambda_k\neq0$ for some $k$. Note that $\lambda_{n+1}=0$ implies that $\lambda_i=0$ for each $i$ since $\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n\}$ is linearly independent. Thus $a_{n+1}\neq0$. Put $\mu_i=-\lambda_i/\lambda_{n+1}$. Then dividing (1) by $\lambda_{n+1}$ and solving for $a_{n+1}$ gives
$$
\mu_1\cdot a_1+\dotsb+\mu_n\cdot a_n=a_{n+1}
$$
a contradiction since $a_{n+1}\not\in\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n\}$. Hence $\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n,a_{n+1}\}$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

let $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} c_i a_i=0$$

Your goal is to show that all the $c_i$ must be $0$.

Consider $2$ cases:

Case $1$: if $c_{n+1}=0$.

Case $2$: if $c_{n+1} \neq 0$, express $a_{n+1}$ as a linear combination of the rest. Try to look for a contradiction.